# Text goes missing on nivo slider in IE on first transition

Tags: internet-explorer

I'm currently using nivo slider on a static html page. The html text goes missing on the first transition in IE 8. It looks fine in FF and Chrome.

When I take away the classes from the spans around the text of slides 4-5 the text displays but unformatted.

Any help on this would be well appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by upgrading jQuery from 1.4 to 1.6.3.

Thanks to all who considered this problem.